# Cannot access file when sending email through SMTP server in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, smtp

I am having an issue when sending emails in C#.

I have an application for sending emails with attachment through our own SMTP server. But before sending the emails, there is another function for creating/merging PDF files. Sometimes it says "can not access file".

I understand that this could be the PDF file is not created yet. The pdf file size is dynamic so it may take different time to finish the creation.

I am wondering if there is a general solution for this? Such as I am sending a request to the server to create PDF files and how can I wait the PDF file to finish?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you checking the response status for 200 OK?

Comment: @jdweng Yes. I am sure it is 200, I am using Angular 9 to send the request. Inside C# program it will not wait for server to finish PDF creation.

Comment: You can only wait for the response.  If server is still creating PDF after the response there is nothing you can do.   Often webpages run java code async so you may get a response before the java completes.  Some times you can parse the webpage for a tag indicating (not null) indicating the java completed.